# Instantiating named GTK widgets in Python

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a simple GUI build with Glade 3 and I have a gtk.Entry widget with name "input_entry1". I would like to instantiate new gtk.Entry widget called "input_entry2" but I would like to do it simply in Python code, not with Glade, but I can't figure out how to set a name to instance of widget (or create a named widget).

Thanks a lot, Tomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you could name your widgets using `gtk_widget_set_name` function. I think in Python you can use `set_name` method:

http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-WidgetNameMethods.html